# Referencing App_Code Class From DLL

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a web site project. I have inherited a C# class file that I would like to put in a DLL, but the class references classes that reside in the App_Code folder. Is is possible to access App_Code classes from a DLL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET websites - as opposed to ASP.NET web projects - are compiled when executed. So when you build them you won't see a .dll output in a bin folder that you could reference from anywhere.

But it wouldn't make sense to use a website as class library anyway. If it contains classes that you need, it would make sense to pull them out of the webiste. That means

- create a new class library project
- move the class files from the website into the new project
- make whatever adjustments are needed to for it to compile.

How well this works may depend on how tightly the code is coupled with the website project in which it lives. For example, a class might look for values in `HttpContext.Current`. If that's the case, the class won't work outside of a website as-is. You'd need to modify it to get inputs differently. (Without seeing the code, it's hard to know whether this will be trivially easy or tedious and frustrating.)

Hopefully if the classes aren't too coupled to the ASP.NET environment you can remove them from your existing website and even that website can use your new class library.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHannen. I'll need to take an alternate approach as the class library I want to create is too tightly coupled to the website.